# Is there any way to compare strings with a startIndex?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I was just wondering if there is a way of comparing c# strings with a startIndex for the first one. I have a long string and an index and want to find if the next characters are equal to a string. The only way I have found to do this is:

```
public static bool Equals (string longString, int index, string compare) => longString.Substring(index, compare.Length) == compare;
```

I think this is inefficient because you are unnecessarily creating a substring for each time you compare a new string at the index. Is there a more efficient way? I looked at string.Equals but it doesn't look like something I would be comfortable trying to rewrite.

Comment: Srings are [indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netcore-3.1), so you could compare the characters at those positions in a loop, accessing them like an array.

Comment: you don't need a loop, see my answer below

Comment: What would be the expected result if `longString = "text containing";` `index = 5;` and `compare = "Contain";`? Notice the capital "C" and(!) the fact that "containing" is technically a different word than "Contain".

Comment: There's a typo or something in the sample code. You should replace `compare.Length` with `compare.Length + index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.Compare(longString, startIndex, compare, 0, compare.Length, isIgnoreCase) == 0;
```

Please see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found.

```
public static bool Equals (string longString, int index, string compare)
{
    if (longString.Length > (index + compare.Length))
        return false;
    for (int n = 0; n < compare.Length; n++)
    {
        if (longString[index + n] != compare[n])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to do an additional check to make sure `index + n` is still within the bounds of `longString`.

Answer (score 0):

[IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_) contains an overload where we can set `startIndex` and check whether the string contains desired word, then we should check if the sub-string after the `startIndex` has the same length as the desired word and note that the following solution doesn't create a new sub-string at all:

```
var startIndex = 2;
var longString = "56789";
var wordToFind = "789";
var isEqual = longString.IndexOf(wordToFind, startIndex) != -1 && wordToFind.Length == (longString.Length - startIndex);
Console.WriteLine(isEqual);
```

Comment: Using a built-in function is the best option, as string lookups are crazily optimized in the BCL and custom reimplementations will usually be worse.

Comment: OP wants to know if the sub-string starting form `index` index of `longString` and ending at `longString.Length - 1` index of `longString` exactly equals `compare`, not contains `compare`.

Comment: @Pautodidactic  The above code is completely satisfies OP and your requirements. If you edit some char to uppercase, then it will return `false`. You can test it.

Comment: `startIndex` is 10 in your example. So the sub-string OP is looking for is `"long string desired string"`. Is `"long string desired string"` equals `"desired string"`? Your example returns `true` because it checks if `"long string desired string"` contains `"desired string"`' and this is not what OP wants. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pautodidactic OP says `I was just wondering if there is a way of comparing c# strings with a startIndex for the first one. I have a long string and an index and want to find if the next characters are equal to a string.` in my view OP wants to find the desired string in long string from desired index.

Comment: In the text in your above comment pay attention to the word "compare" which means "is equal or not" not contains, and "want to find if the next characters are **equal** to a string." is obvious. If you have any doubts again see the sample code and read it carefully. `Substring(...) == ...` is telling everything.

Comment: @Pautodidactic his code checks whether the chars are the same `longString[index + n] != compare[n]`. My code does the same.

Comment: Your code checks if it contains, not equals. Consider this **:** `"56789".IndexOf("6")` which returns `1` and  `"56789".IndexOf("4")` which returns `-1`. `IndexOf()` returns `-1` when there is no for example `"4"` in `"56789"` means it returns `-1` when `"56789"` does not contains `"4"`' not **equals**. Consider this part of your code **:** `longString.IndexOf(wordToFind, startIndex) == -1` it checks  whether `longString` after `startIndex` contains `wordToFind`. Again Tell me if I'm wrong. Your code doesn't the same stuff as OP's.

Comment: as I said `"56789".IndexOf("6")` returns a value rather than `-1`. Does it mean `"56789"` equals `"6"`? or contains `"6"`?

Comment: @Pautodidactic ooops, you are right! Thanks for clarification! Please, see my updated answer

Comment: I think you should change `1` in `longString.Length - 1` to `startIndex`